# Why doesn't Control Key trigger KeyDown event? (UWP)

Tags: c#, events, uwp, keydown

I am listening to KeyDown events because I want to cycle through my PivotItems with Control+(Shift)+Tab. However, the Control and Shift key don't trigger the event. Why is that?

In code behind:

```
rootPivot.KeyDown += (s, e) => {
            if(Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control).HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) && e.Key == VirtualKey.Tab) {
                //Change selected index
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually to trigger all the keys you should use **PreviewKeyDown** event. Make sure you set e.Handled based on your need.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.previewkeydown

```
/*XAML Code*/
    <Page
        x:Class="App1.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:App1"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid>
            <Pivot x:Name="RootPivot" PreviewKeyDown="RootPivot_PreviewKeyDown">
                <PivotItem Header="Item1"></PivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="Item2"></PivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="Item3"></PivotItem>
            </Pivot>
        </Grid>
    </Page>
 //C# code

  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        public MainPage()
        {

            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void RootPivot_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Control)
            {
                MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("You pressed control");
                await dialog.ShowAsync();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why some controls prevent certain keydown events? I noticed that Pivot ignores Control, Shift and even Left/Right arrow keys. Edit: Also, I just tested it with PreviewKeyDown and said keys don't trigger this event either. Do I have to make a new class and override the event?

Comment: Yeah, for example in a textbox control arrow keys won't trigger keydown event. because those keys are defined to some other action. If a down arrow is pressed while in a textbox it will goto the end of the text. Side arrow will navigate between characters. So to ensure all the keys the PreviewKeyDown is added.

Comment: I just tested it with preview event. Still not triggered :/

Comment: I just tried it works fine. Okay i will edit my answer and will add the code.

Comment: I don't know why but it's not working for me :( I'll wait until tomorrow before accepting your answer - since it's working for you - just in case I get more replies.

Comment: Try tapping on one pivot item then try to trigger ctrl key.

Comment: Just to add this: turns out my problem was caused by the VM I'm running windows in. It somehow affects the keyboard behaviour. Natively, Pivot already switches between PivotItems when using Ctrl+(Shift)+Tab